# WLAN: how to configure entropy file in wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: wireless-networking, security, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wpa-supplicant

`wpa_passphrase` creates network login information for `wpa_supplicant.conf`.
`wpa_supplicant` takes an option `-e` to store entropy across restarts.

I understand internally stored entropy as a way to make connections more *secure*, because it is hard for an attacker to correctly guess it.

The option `-e` nicely works when I manually call `wpa_supplicant`, but Raspberry Pi invokes the `wpa_supplicant` service already at startup, and I would like to keep this.

- Where is the default entropy store on the RasPi (running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11)?
- Where in the RPi can I configure that location for the `wpa_supplicant` service?
- Can I do so in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wpa_passphrase creates network login information for wpa_supplicant.conf. wpa_supplicant takes an option -e to store entropy across restarts.

These two have nothing to do with each other. Information stored in wpa_supplicant.conf is deterministic – the "psk=" parameter is strictly just a PBKDF2 hash of your passphrase and the network SSID.

Entropy (random data) is needed later – during every authentication handshake, where both

> I understand internally stored entropy as a way to make connections more secure, because it is hard for an attacker to correctly guess it.

Yes but there's slightly more to the story than that.

In most Linux systems, programs can just *ask the OS* for high-quality random data, e.g. by reading from the /dev/[u]random virtual device or by using the getentropy() system call. The reason for wpa_supplicant to have its own internal storage is more specific, as described below.

> Where is the default entropy store on the RasPi (running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11)?

The random data facility provided by the OS doesn't have a permanent "entropy store" by default – the entropy pool is initialized fresh on every boot, using data from various hardware sources.

But the problem comes when the hardware platform doesn't have any good sources to collect entropy from (for example, a Raspberry Pi doesn't have a real-time clock; many Linux-based access points are tiny SoCs with few external inputs), in which case the entropy pool initialization could take a *long* time. Some Linux distributions add an OS-wide "entropy store" file for that purpose (usually somewhere in /var/lib), allowing programs to continue using /dev/[u]random on such systems.

(This was especially a problem with older Linux versions, where /dev/random and /dev/urandom worked differently – reading from the former would deplete the OS "entropy pool" quickly, forcing programs to wait, while the latter could provide low-quality random data if read too early.)

So wpa_supplicant's internal entropy pool and the "entropy file" options are specifically for use in systems which *do not* have a functioning OS-wide entropy pool, such as cheap MIPS-based SoCs. (wpa_supplicant comes from the "hostapd" project which is used to build access points.) You generally don't need to use the `-e` option on regular Linux systems.

Also, if you're running a systemd-based Linux distribution on your Raspberry Pi, it already uses /var/lib/systemd/random-seed to help with OS entropy pool initialization on startup (and it's probably running a recent kernel with improvements to entropy collection as well).

> Where in the RPi can I configure that location for the wpa_supplicant service?

You configure the options *in* the wpa_supplicant service.

If you're running Linux with systemd, use `systemctl cat` to take a look at the service definition; the `ExecStart=` line specifically. Depending on distribution, there are two options:

- Sometimes the configured command line will include a variable such as `$WPA_ARGS`. This comes from a file specified in an EnvironmentFile= setting in the same service definition (commonly located in /etc/default/ or /etc/sysconfig/), so edit that file and run `systemctl daemon-reload`.
- Sometimes it does not, and all options are defined directly in the ExecStart= parameter. In this case, run `systemctl edit --full wpa_supplicant` to edit it directly – your customized service file will be stored in /etc/systemd/system/ to override the distribution one.